# Stopping thread does not work

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that listens for data send through a stream. because the networkstream.read method is synchronous I have to execute that on a separate thread. so the method that I execute on a separate thread is:

```
void someMethod(param1, param2....)
{
    try{
     while( stream.read(data...) != 0 )  // code waits here until data is received
     {
        // do stufff

     } 
    }catch{}//
}
```

the only way I am able to exit that thread is by closing the stream and the catch block will execute. I sometimes need to start listening for data on the same stream but on a different method.  so if I create the thread as   Thread t = new Thread(new threadstart(somemethod......)   then do t.start( someObject);  later when I do  t.abort() ;  that method will still be listening for data. How can I terminate it?

also I have tried creating a global variable such as:

```
bool someBoolean = false;

void someMethod(param1, param2....)
{
    try{
     while(someBoolean ==false && stream.read(data...) != 0 )  // code waits here until data is received
     {
        // do stufff

     } 
    }catch{}//
}
```

then I figured that I changed someBoolean to true the method will stop executing. for some reason it does not. Why? it seems like someBoolean is two variables at once. Because changing its value from the main thread does not seem to impact it on the second thread...

Comment: you should read from the stream in a buffered way, means read small amount of data in the while. show real code on how you are doing your read and your do stuff and the way your thread is working...

Comment: `stream.Read` will block until data is available, so setting the boolean doesn't help at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the thread might be abortet but then the resources from that thread (unmanaged because of stream) will not be freed - that is your problem.

Don't stop the thread with abort - never.

Do stop it try using a async version of stream.read together with a CancellationToken.
If you give us more info (what stream? - read is strange ("R"ead?), starting of the thread) I might try to give you more details.

PS: try using System.Threading.Task instead of threads - way nicer to work with.

as a quick fix without further info, you could try something like this:

```
ManualThreadEvent terminate = new ManualThreadEvent(false);
bool someBoolean = false;

void someMethod(param1, param2....)
{
    try{
     // wait for enough data or for termination:
     while(terminate.WaitOne(100) == false && stream.DataAvaiable <= bytesNeeded) 
     { /* nothing to do here */ }

     if (terminate.WaitOne(0)) return; // terminate on request

     // To your stuff with read
    }catch{}//
}

void Terminate()
{
  terminate.Set();
}
```

Comment: it will be nice to create a async version of stream.read. stream is of type NetworkStream and I basically create it when creating a tcp connection between a server (tcpListener object) and client.

Comment: NetworkStream is no problem (just look for BeginRead/EndRead) - but it's allway better to give us code that will compile - this above are just fragments and it's hard to give you good advice. As I said use the async versions and consider switching to Tasks - if you use the CancellationToken-stuff you should do fine. Also note that you can use .DataAvailable your stream to check for data and then sleep a short time (or wait for a termination signal for a short time)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I terminate it?

The standard protocol for unsticking a blocked stream call is to close the stream and catch the exception. Interrupting a read just so you can move it off to a different method is fairly unusual. If you feel like this is still necessary then you should provide an extra level of indirection on the read operation. It is a lot easier to deal with scenarios like this when using asynchronous calls like `BeginRead` as opposed to the synchronous calls. Terminating a thread via `Thread.Abort` can cause a lot more problems than it solves.

> then I figured that I changed someBoolean to true the method will stop
>   executing. for some reason it does not. Why? it seems like someBoolean
>   is two variables at once. Because changing its value from the main
>   thread does not seem to impact it on the second thread...

It is possible that a lack of a memory barrier can cause this problem, but the more likely cause is that the thread is stuck inside `Read` and is not actually reading `someBoolean` the way you hoped it would.